# Vuejs: I can't generate new content for the same vue element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

I'm filling an HTML file with some jquery generated html, that works fine:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data:{
        coordDeltoidder:  "434,398,415,359,386,327,356,286,380,282,414,292,437,323,443,350",
        coordDeltoidizq:  "167,404,154,377,153,346,183,304,235,291,211,337,179,368",
        coordBicepsder:   "136,378,170,460",
        coordBicepsizq:   "434,367,467,466",
        coordBrachialder: "160,372,210,483",
        coordBrachializq: "394,363,444,467",
        wrong: 1,
        puntos: 0,
        rta1: "biceps",
        rta2: "deltoides",
        rta3: "erector spinae",
        rta4: ["isquiotibiales", "aductores", "cuadriceps"],
        rta5: "cuello"
    },
    created: function () {
        this.renderFrontmuscles();
    },
    methods:{
        renderFrontmuscles(){
            $('#musclemap').html('<area shape="poly"    v-bind:coords=coordDeltoidizq  @mouseover="deltoidHigh"    @mouseleave="baseImage"    @click="deltoidSelec"/>'
                                +'<area shape="poly"    v-bind:coords=coordDeltoidder  @mouseover="deltoidHigh"    @mouseleave="baseImage"    @click="deltoidSelec"/>'
                                +'<area shape="rect"    v-bind:coords=coordBicepsder   @mouseover="bicepsHigh"    @mouseleave="baseImage"     @click="bicepsSelec"/>'
                                +'<area shape="rect"    v-bind:coords=coordBicepsizq   @mouseover="bicepsHigh"    @mouseleave="baseImage"     @click="bicepsSelec"/>'
                                +'<area shape="rect"    v-bind:coords=coordBrachialder @mouseover="brachialHigh"    @mouseleave="baseImage"   @click="brachialSelec"/>'
                                +'<area shape="rect"    v-bind:coords=coordBrachializq @mouseover="brachialHigh"    @mouseleave="baseImage"   @click="brachialSelec"/>');
        },
```

I have some methods to place another image over the base image to simulate a selection over the base image, the issue is that when I "deselect" this other image using this method:

```
muscleDeselect(){
       $('#muscDiv').html('');
       //no toma funciones ni datos
       this.renderFrontmuscles();
},
```

the renderFrontmuscles() method doesn't regenerates the v-bind data, it generates i.e. v-bind:coords=coordBicepsizq instead of coords="434,367,467,466".

I really don't know what to do.

Comment: the way you are mixing the two bypasses vue's reactivity. it is generally not a good idea to use vue with jQuery. Write the html template in the component's `template` option. that should help. then you will not need the created hook. Check the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Composing-with-Components) for more info

Comment: I've done that and I changed all the Jquery for pure Javascript, works in the same way. The <area> are generated, but the v-bind keeps giving me the coordBicepsizq instead of the coords numbers.